# Write custom symbols in text

Tags: game-design

My game use boxes □ that are marked with one or more line depending on how many times they are used. They can be marked up to 3 times, first with a single line like 〼, then ☒, finally a third horizontal line over the X.

I suspect there is a "best practice" for working with custom symbols in text like this, but what is it?

As you see above some are available as unicode symbols, but not all and not in a uniform size. Handling them as images works in some cases but becomes difficult as they break up the text flow in any word-processor style text like instructions. I have looked at various symbol fonts without any luck.

Comment: Could you elaborate what issues you're having with images? An image smaller than your line height shouldn't be a problem for a text editor.

Comment: How much space is available for this "box"? You could do better using an alternative 1-2-3 counting system than a / or x or * setup.

Comment: And for what is it used in the end? Integration into a game engine might have a different solution than for printing a physical copy.

Comment: You show the empty box as  □ but this ☐ seems to be the same size as these 〼 ☒ ☑. Can't find one with a horizontal bar as mentioned. Perhaps 1, 2, and 3 lines can be these – = ≡ symbols.

Comment: I'm now thinking of things like custom emoji/symbols syntax like `:box:` or `:box-1:` but I have no idea if that's a standard for writing rules text. I know that Magic uses braces as placeholders for game symbols (`{R}` represents the red mana symbol).

Comment: Small images like Cadence mentions is actually a working solution, I guesss I just assumed there would be something more "elegant". A game like Magic should certainly have a good way to deal with this - whatever they do should work for me too except it could be an issue if placeholder has a different size. Symbols will be used in physical game props, cards, instructions as well as online material.

Comment: I know for web-stuff ist's common to include vectorized icons/logos/symbols in the font itself. There are many websites that help with this process. If those fonts are viable to use in a boardgame/print setting, I don't know.